# Apache StrTokenizer How To Escape Quote and Comma in String Literal

Tags: java, apache, tokenize, stringtokenizer

I have this code to parse some csv, given the understanding that doing double quote escapes the quote within the string literal (as said in the Apache docs)

```
private void test() {
    char quote = '\'';
    char delim = ',';
    // should be split into [comma, comma], [quote ', comma]
    String inputListValues = "'comma, comma', 'quote '', comma'";
    StrTokenizer st = new StrTokenizer(inputListValues, delim, quote);
    List<String> vals = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (st.hasNext()) {
        vals.add(st.nextToken().trim());
    }
    System.out.println(vals);

    // should be split into [quote ', comma], [comma, comma]
    String inputListValues2 = "'quote '', comma', 'comma, comma'";
    StrTokenizer st2 = new StrTokenizer(inputListValues2, delim, quote);
    List<String> vals2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (st2.hasNext()) {
        vals2.add(st2.nextToken().trim());
    }
    System.out.println(vals2);
}
```

the output is

```
vals    ArrayList<E>  (id=1088) 
    [0] "comma, comma" (id=1063)    
    [1] "'quote ''" (id=1036)   
    [2] "comma'" (id=2123)  

vals2   ArrayList<E>  (id=2296) 
    [0] "quote ', comma" (id=1920)  
    [1] "'comma" (id=1852)  
    [2] "comma'" (id=1316)
```

I'm expecting 2 items parsed: [quote ', comma], [comma, comma]

If it didn't work at all it would be one thing, but it seems like changing the order causes the parsing to change the behavior.

Does anyone have any idea?  I'm on the verge of just using another library or regex.

Answer (score 0):

It's because I started using this with "csv parser" in mind, however it's not.  The docs say

```
"a, ", b ,", c" - Three tokens "a, " , " b ", ", c" (quoted text untouched)
```

So spaces are part of the token.  I added then used setTrimmerMatcher, since for a trimmer matcher:

```
These characters are trimmed off on each side of the delimiter until the token or quote is found.
```

Code ended up being

```
StrTokenizer st = new StrTokenizer(toTokenize, DELIM_CHAR, QUOTE_CHAR);
// by default this is a STRING matching, not csv parser, so spaces count as part of the token
//  ie "a, ", b ,", c" - Three tokens "a, " , " b ", ", c" (quoted text untouched)
// thus we set the trimmer matcher, which "are trimmed off on each side of the delimiter until the token or quote is found."
st.setTrimmerMatcher(StrMatcher.trimMatcher());
```